# How do I return a history of data without using an array (and also delete it)?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA (very first day, so please be patient). I would like to get stock histories from Yahoo Finance (via a UDF) then return the values. [This tutorial](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/07/08/excel-udf-import-historical-stock-prices-from-yahoo/) explains it but I really hate the whole having to press ctrl + shift + Return method b/c you have to know the length of the data, among other annoyances.

How can I do it like [Bloomberg does](http://www.gsb.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/bloomberg_0.pdf) where you just enter "=BDH(Security,Field,Start Date,End Date)", then just hit Enter and it populates all the cells?
Also, when I delete the UDF, I would need to delete those values (as Bloomberg also does).

The following code doesn't work and gives me an "Application-defined or object-defined error" error:

```
Function ms()
On Error GoTo do_error
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value = "hello"
    ms = 12
    Exit Function
do_error:
    ms = Err.Description
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: Functions can't change the value of other cells. If you search along those lines you'll get more info.

Comment: How does Bloomberg do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried not to change your code too much,

A function returns a variable, (or else its a SUB)

So,

```
Function ms() as Long  'or String or whatever it returns
On Error GoTo do_error
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value = "hello"
    ms = 12
    Exit Function
do_error:
    ms = Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: i changed just the 1rst line by adding "as long"